# Bluetooth Problem in Loki 0.4.1

Tags: bluetooth

does anyone know how to unblock bluetooth (soft blocked) in Loki?

Here is my rfkill list output in case needed:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is actually an Asus laptop in terminal do

`rfkill unblock bluetooth`

If it isn't an Asus laptop

`echo "blacklist asus-wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus-blacklist.conf`

Reboot

Comment: the first command is working, but now my airplane light indicator light up whenever i turned on the bluetooth lol. thanks btw!